# flash will not start automatically playing video and video advancement fails?

Tags: vb.net, flash, video

I am having trouble getting my current vb.net code to start automatically playing random video trailers retrieved from trailer addicts API service (I only return 6 of them at a time). In addition, I can play the first video but other videos fail to allow me to let me play them manually too with an error about protected memory being accessed. Here's the code:

```
  Private Sub TrailerRotateTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TrailerRotateTimer.Tick
    If FirstTrailer = False Then
        Select Case myoptions.TrailerPlayTime
            Case Is = 60
                TrailerRotateTimer.Interval = 60000
                FirstTrailer = True
            Case Is = 90
                TrailerRotateTimer.Interval = 90000
                FirstTrailer = True
            Case Is = 120
                TrailerRotateTimer.Interval = 120000
                FirstTrailer = True
            Case Else
                TrailerRotateTimer.Interval = 60000
                FirstTrailer = True
        End Select

    End If
    firstvideo = myoptions.TrailerUrlCollection.Item(randnum.Next(1, 5))
    ' Video.EmbedMovie = True
    Video.AllowScriptAccess = "always"
    Video.FlashVars = ""
    ' Video.Playing = True

    Video.LoadMovie(0, firstvideo)

    If Video.IsPlaying = False Then
        ' Video.CallFunction("<invoke name=""id"" returntype=""xml""><arguments><string>100788</string></arguments></invoke>")
        Video.Play()
        'Video.Playing = True
        'Video.Loop = False
    Else
        Video.Stop()
        Video.Play()
    End If
End Sub
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? 
P.S. here's the direct link I found to the SWF file if needed: http://v.traileraddict.com/js/flash/player.swf?id=100788&e=y&id=100788

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint and follow the code? Also, get rid of the `Is` in your Case statements. Just write `Case 60` etc.

Comment: It only happens once the timer loads the next trailer and I press play manually. Otherwise, it play's the first trailer manually. I have a sub main that calls and creates the form. It errors out around/after LoadMovie though.

Comment: I received a comment from the traileraddict admin and it was by design in their SWF file. The admin said a variable was being added so the video could be played automatically. So, for now if anyone has code that plays multiple videos in a flash control, I will accept that as answer.